# Number of inflection points of $\log f(x)$ vs. $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am wondering, is there some (general) theorem or lemma (that I am not aware of) which would state something about number of inflection points of a logarithm of a positive function if we know the number of inflection points of the function (or the other way)?

In other words, if we know that a positive function $f(x)$ has $n$ inflection points, can we say something about number of inflection points of $\log f(x)$? Also the other way. If we know that $\log f(x)$ has $m$ inflection points, can we say something about number of inflection points of $f(x)$? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you think that log affects the number of inflection points of a function?

Comment: Well, for example even in simple case $f(x)=x^3+1$ there is one inflection point ($x=0$). But if we take the logarithm, i.e., $\log f(x)$ has two inflection points $x=0, x=\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: Of course one should restrict $f$ to be positive-valued in the first place, to make this a sensible question.

Comment: Of course I meant positive function. Sorry for the error. I fixed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Horizontal inflexions of the original curve are in one-to-one correspondence with horizontal inflexions of the log curve. Apart from that, there is no connexion.**

Consider the *regular* curve parametrised by $\gamma(t) = (t,x(t))$. The curve has an inflexion  if and only if the first two derivatives are linearly dependent, i.e. $\dot{\gamma}\parallel \ddot{\gamma}$. In otherwords: $\ddot{x}(t)=0$.

Next, consider the curve $\alpha(t)=(t,\ln x(t))$. We have $\dot{\alpha}(t) = (1,\dot{x}/x)$ and 
$$\ddot{\alpha}(t) = \left(0,\frac{x\ddot{x}-\dot{x}^2}{x^2}\right)$$.

Assuming that $x>0$ then $\dot{\alpha}\parallel \ddot{\alpha}$ if, and only if, $x\ddot{x}-\dot{x}^2=0$. If $\gamma(t_0)$ is an inflexion then we *also need* $\dot{x}(t_0)=0$ for $\alpha(t_0)$ to be an inflexion. If $\alpha(t_0)$ is an inflexion then we need $\dot{x}(t_0)=0$ for $\gamma(t_0)$ to be an inflexion.

Hence, for $x>0$, if $\dot{x}=0$ then $\gamma(t_0)$ is an inflexion if, and only if, $\alpha(t_0)$ is an inflexion.

The log curve $\alpha$ is free to have inflexions when the original $\gamma$ does not: we simply need $\dot{x}\neq 0$ at such points. Conversely, the original curve $\gamma$ is free to have inflexions when the log curve $\alpha$ does not: we just need $\dot{x} \neq 0$ at that point.

Comment: This is a valid argument, but only for one very special case of inflection points.

Comment: @GregMartin That's all the OP was interested in, the "...number of inflection points of a logarithm of a positive function."

Comment: Well, no: this argument treats only points where the original function has derivative $0$.

Comment: @GregMartin No it doesn't It give a condition for the original curve to have an inflexion: $\ddot{x}(t_0)=0$ and for the log curve to have an inflexion: $(x\ddot{x}-\dot{x}^2)(t_0)=0$. That only assumes the curve is a graph of a function. I then relate the inflexions on both curves. Feel free to add an answer if you can do any better.

Comment: @Fly by Night I'm really not sure so correct me, but aren't the conditions you state necessary ones? The *if and only if* concers me. I thought that sufficiency was given by the first non-zero derivative being of odd order?

Comment: I state several conditions. The first ones says that if $\alpha$ has an inflexion then we need $\dot{x}=0$ for $\gamma$ to have one. The second says that if $\gamma$ has an inflexion then we need $\dot{x}=0$ for $\alpha$ to have one. The third says that at points where $\dot{x}=0$, $\alpha$ has an inflexion if and only if $\gamma$ does. Finally I show that, in general, there is no connexion when $\dot{x} \neq 0$.

Comment: @FlybyNight I must say I really like your answer although I am still processing it:). Can you maybe explain what do you mean by "horizontal inflexions"? Thanks.

Comment: @pisoir A horizontal inflexion is an inflexion where the tangent line to the curve at that point is horizontal. For example, $y=x^3$ has a horizontal inflexion at $(0,0)$; the tangent line is the $x$-axis. The curve $y=\sin x$ has an inflexion at $(0,0)$ and the tangent line there is the line $y=x$. That is not a horizontal inflexion. (In school people are taught that inflexions are just horizontal inflexions, but this isn't true.)

Comment: @FlybyNight What about the case I commented in the first answer. $f(x)=x^3+1$. As I understand this is also a horizontal inflexion at $0$. But logarithm has two inflection points $0$ but also $\sqrt[3]{2}$. As I understand, what you are saying is that there is one-to-relation with those horizontal inflexions, but there can be some more inflexions in addition.

Comment: Let $\mathscr{O}$ be the original curve and $\mathscr{L}$ the log curve. If $\mathscr{O}$ has a horizontal inflexion at $x=x_1$ then $\mathscr{L}$ has a horizontal inflexion at $x=x_1$. Moreover, if $\mathscr{L}$ has a horizontal inflexion at $x=x_1$ then $\mathscr{O}$ has a horizontal inflexion at $x=x_1$. One can only have a h-inflexion if the other does too. *However*, both curves are free to have as many non-horizontal inflexions as they want, and where ever they want, and there is no connexion whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

In general, there is no relationship.

For example, take $f(x) = e^{x+(\sin x)/10}$. One can check that $f$ has no inflection points but $\log f$ has infinitely many inflection points.

On the other hand, let $h$ be a solution to the differential equation $h'(x) = (-1 + (\sin x)/2) h(x)^2$ (with say $h(0)=1$, on say $x\in[0,\infty)$). Let $g(x)$ be an antiderivative of $h(x)$, and let $f(x) = e^{g(x)}$. The inflection points of $f$ occur precisely where $g''(x)+g'(x)^2=0$ and thus where $h'(x) = -h(x)^2$, which are the infinitely many multiples of $\pi$. However, one can show that $h$ is positive and decreasing on $[0,\infty)$; therefore $g''(x)=h'(x)$ is never zero, hence $g=\log f$ has no inflection points.

Comment: wow how did you come up with these examples?

Answer (score 0):

Write out the two successive derivatives (assuming $f\in\mathcal C^2$): $$\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}(\log\circ f)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{f''f-(f')^2}{f^2}$$
We want this to be zero at some $x\in\mathbb R$: $$f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2=0$$

So we can see that all the original (stationary) inflection points of $f$ restricted to $(0,\infty)$ are still inflection points, but there's no clear way of knowing whether there's more, without additional information about $f$. Notice that we may have lost any inflection points that were in the negative domain of $f$. We cannot conclude anything if $f'(x)\not = 0$.

Comment: Actually, there's the caveat that there can be less if the values of $f$ are negative over a certain range, because the $\log$ can't be evaluated there.

Comment: This is false, because there's no reason that $f'(x)$ should also equal $0$ at the inflection point. For example, take $f(x) = x^3+x+1$. Then $f(x)$ has an inflection point at $x=0$, while the inflection points of $\log f(x)$ are near $x=0.167056$ and $x=1.19858$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Well spotted! fixed it.

Comment: @GregMartin, In the context I though we were talking about saddle type inflection points, but I've edited for full correction

Comment: @GregMartin Now it should be ok

Comment: @GPerez. Thanks for the comment. Does it mean that finding the solutions of your second equation (non-linear differential equation) actually give us the (only) possible functions $f(x)$ for which $\log f(x)$ has inflection points?

Comment: @pisoir **No!** Solving that ODE would give a curve that has inflexions at every single point. You want $x\ddot{x}-\dot{x}=0$ *at a point* for *that point* to be an inflexion.

Comment: @pisoir Somewhat... If you solved the differential equation $f''f-f'^2=0$, What you'd obtain is a function $f$ such that $log\circ f$, differentiated twice is the zero function. This means it's zero everywhere, i.e. $(log\circ f)''(x)=0$, no matter what $x$ from the domain. The equation in the answer isn't a differential equation for that reason, because you want a point that, when evaluated gives 0, instead of a *function* that is 0 everywhere

Comment: @GPerez. Thanks. I see your points. (e.g. $f(x)=e^x$ is a solution to that "ODE", and also  $(\log f(x))''=0$, but it does not say anything about the inflection points.)

Comment: @FlybyNight "a curve that has inflexions at every single point"...That's an interesting concept! Do you think there are there any such functions other than constant ones?

Comment: @GPerez I don't think you can say that a constant function is concave nor convex. Then you can't say that it has any inflection points.

Comment: @pisoir Constant functions are, in a manner of speaking, right on the border between concave and convex, actually! Take $f: f(x)=c \ \forall x$. Then $f(tx+(1-t)y)=c=tc+(1-t)c=tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ So the condition for being convex is always at the equality (e.g. "borderline convex"). Or, $f''=0$ so for all $x,\epsilon$, $f''(x-\epsilon)=-f''(x+\epsilon)$, (because $0=-0$) i.e. the second derivative changes sign at every point, so by definition every point is a point of inflection!

Answer (score 0):

See here----
Actually the points of inflection of a function $y=f(x)$ means,where the function $y=f(x)$ has its 2nd order derivative equals to zero.
or we can say mathematically where or for what values of  $x$ the function has its 2nd order derivative = 0.   OR  $f '' ( x ) = 0 $.

the values of $x$ for which the equation  $f'' (x) = 0$ is satisfied we can say those points in the domain of the function,it has the points of inflections or the $f '' (x)$ is $0$.

See where the function has its 2nd order derivative $f '' (x) = 0$ , at that values of $x$ the function $y = f(x)$ is changing its behavior from *concave down* to *concave up* or *concave up* to *concave down*.

Mathematically we can say if a function $y = f (x)$ has its $f '' (x)$ (2nd order derivative) less than $0$ or $f " (x) < 0$ or its $f '' (x)$ value is negative  in a certain scale of $x$  then you can say that  *the function is just concave down* or if we draw the curve of $y = f(x)$ in a co-ordinate system we will have a curve just having a *concave down* nature.
And similarly if the function has its $f'' (x ) > 0$ in certain scale of $x$ then we say that the function has a *concave up* characteristics and if we draw the graph of $y= f(x)$ we will have just a *concave up* picture of the function $y = f(x)$.

please go to the link : coz I dont have the software to upload answer with pic.
The link is the graph of a simple function to implement the concepts which I said earlier above.
The link is a picture of a graph of $y = x^3$.
You can go through the link or you can have a google search for it for better understanding along with my concepts....

[graph](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=graph+of+x%5E3&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=nfXWUp2dC47AkQfG_4GwCw&sqi=2&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=664#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=Ola0WCogiDItHM%253A%3BvNGGNy0xtOWiMM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.s-cool.co.uk%252Fgcse%252Fassets%252Flearn_its%252Fgcse%252Fmaths%252Fgraphs%252Falgebraic-graphs%252Fg-mat-graph-dia04.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.s-cool.co.uk%252Fgcse%252Fmaths%252Fgraphs%252Frevise-it%252Falgebraic-graphs%3B300%3B247)

See here  at the point $x=0$ the $f ''( x )$ of the function $f(x) = x^3$
that is $f'' (x) = 3(x^2)$ is equal to zero. See $f '' (x)$ for $x=0$ is  $f'' (0) = 3(0^2) = 0$.

So you see there is the point of inflection at $x=0$ in the curve of the function $y = f(x)$.
and see if  $x>0$ the $f'' (x)= 3x^2$ is also greater than $0$. So it is *concave up* for $x>0$
and it is also true for $x<0$ and it is *concave down* when $x<0$.

But see here the log $f(x)$ will be:  let us consider  $g(x)  =  \log f(x) = \log {x^3} =  3\log x$.

Now if you have the second order derivative of $\log {x^3}$ or   $3\log x$ , you will have  $g'' (x) =  \frac{- 3 }{ x^2}$.

see the function $g(x) = \log f(x)$ has no such points where the second order derivative is 0. 
So, 
There is no *points of inflections* for the function $g(x) = \log f(x)$.

I was trying to make your concept on *points of inflections* and see there is no such direct dependency between the number of inflection points for the function $f(x)$
 and  $\log f(x)$.

the function $\log f(x)$ will have the point of inflection at that values of $x$ for which the equation:      $ \frac{( f(x) f " (x)  -   (f ' (x))^2 )}{  ((f(x))^2) }  = 0$ has a solution for $x$.
Or simply you can say if the equation :
        $$                                                                f(x) f ''(x)  -  (f ' (x) )^2 = 0$$
has any  solution for $x$ or not.

If this equation has any solution then the function $g(x) = \log (f(x))$ will have the points of inflection. And you can also draw the curve of  $y = f(x)$ or  $g(x) = \log f(x)$ by applying the 2nd order derivative criteria.

Hope the answer will help you a bit.Best of luck.

Comment: Nice concepts, though I have to specify that a point of inflection is when $f''(x)$ *changes sign*, which implies that $f''(x)=0$, but $f''(x)=0$ alone isn't enough to say that there's a point of inflection!

Comment: @arkadeep Thanks for explaining what an inflection point is;). Please, fix your errors in the explanation: $(x^3)^{''}\ne 3x^2$ but $(x^3)''=6x$. Then also your explanantion about the fact that $f''(x)>0$ for $x>0$ and $f''(x)<0$ for $x<0$ makes more sense.